# In which iOS 7 method should I write the following code?

Tags: objective-c, ios7

I have a piece of code that asynchronously loads an image into an ImageView like this

```
[self.weatherImage sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://openweathermap.org/img/w/10d.png"]];
[self.weatherImage reloadInputViews];
```

Here, I am using SDWebImage library to load the image into the ImageView. The strange question I have is this:

When I run the program from Xcode, it all runs fine and the image loads neatly into the ImageView. But, if I stop the app from Xcode, and then turn towards my iPad and then open the app from the iPad screen, I don't see the image loading anywhere.

I have tried to put this piece of code in ViewDidAppear(), then ViewDidLoad() and also in awakeFromNib() methods, but none of them seem to load the image if the app is opened from the iPad after it has been run once.

Where should such a functionality be implemented?

Comment: And what did the documentation for this library say?  Also... does your iPad have Internet access?

Comment: Are you using XIB or Storyboard to load `weatherImage` view? Try deleting the app and cleaning the target = general hygiene :)

Comment: @nhgrif: The SDWebImage is an asynchronous image loading library. Nothing specific about anything like this situation.

Comment: @iMartin: I am using iOS 7 Storyboard here.

Comment: in first case are you running app in simulator?

Comment: @Rafeek: No, I am running the app on my iPad. It requires capturing the user's location and several other things, so cannot run those functionality in the simulator.